# Docker - Should my MySQL database live inside or outside the container?

Tags: mysql, database, docker

I'm setting up my first production server on docker but I'm not sure where my MSQL database should live. Should the database live outside the container or within? I've read some articles/posts previously that it should live outside so nothing changes if you have to fire up a new container or image, but I'm not sure if this is correct or not. Are there any speed/performance differences with having it inside or outside of the container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. These are some of the responsibilities of our Database Administrators:

   - Establish and maintain sound backup and recovery policies and procedures
   - Implement and maintain database security (create and maintain users and roles, assign privileges)
   - Perform database tuning and performance monitoring
   - Perform application tuning and performance monitoring
   - Setup and maintain documentation and standards
   - Plan growth and changes (capacity planning)

If I need any of these services I use a database outside of the container and hosted by specialists.

2. If the data needs to be accessed by other applications I use a database on a centralized database server outside of the container and hosted by specialists.

Answer (score 1):

**On performance:** Docker containers use a virtual network interface by default, see [Docker Advanced networking documentation](https://docs.docker.com/v1.6/articles/networking/). This comes with just a slight speed overhead. Still, depending on your expected load, you might want to either bind your DB container to the host network or not dockerize your DB at all.

**On data persistence:** If you are using [volumes or volume containers](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/) your data lives outside the container and can be mounted by any new container too. No worries here.

**On whether to use containers for DBs (my opinion):** It is currently en vogue to containerize stateless and interchangeable applications, meaning that you can simply throw away outdated services and replace them by new containers. While this really makes sense for frequently updated microservices… do you really need this for a comparatively long-lived service like databases? Yes, Docker still helps to contain dependencies and ship stuff faster, but there are alternatives like Ansible-provisioned VMs. In the end it depends on what is easiest for your use case.